# Files not being displayed on mounted ex-FAT sd card on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: usb, mount, 19.04, sd-card, exfat

I have a sandisk sd card which has some images. The sd-card gets mounted but displays that there are no files on the sd-card. However, when I boot to windows on my dual-boot, windows have no problem in displaying the contents. These are not even hidden files.

Let me know if this is some bug or limitation of exfat systems on Ubuntu currently.

Comment: do you have packages `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` installed?  They are needed to read/write from exFAT.  You can install them in terminal: `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`

Comment: @Nmath Yes, I have them installed.

Comment: if you navigate to the mount point using `cd /path/to/mount` and run the `dir` command, does anything show up?

Comment: dir: reading directory 'DCIM/101_FUJI/': Input/output error